# Почему не выстрелил асинк?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular8

Мой код прелоадера:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
  private preloaderState$ = new Subject<boolean>();

  activate() {
    this.preloaderState$.next(true);
  }

  disactivate() {
    this.preloaderState$.next(false);
  }

  preloader(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.preloaderState$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Код шаблона:

```
<div *ngIf="spinnerService.preloader() | async">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: а почему он должен **выстрелить** (смешное слово :) :) ) ?

Comment: потому что я посылаю ему команду `this.service.activate();` из компонента

Comment: создай _воспроизводимый пример_, посмотрим почему он не выстреливает =)

Comment: ты же показал код сервиса, но от него толку как бы нету... лучше бы показал код компонента. Да и еще использовать методы, которые возвращают Observable - нельзя, потому что методы вызываются каждый раз, как Angular совершает change detection, и каждый раз возвращает новый Observable и async pipe каждый раз переподписывается. Могу дать отсечку 99%, что если ты заменишь Subject на BehaviorSubject, то все заработает

Comment: а что использоват вместо метода? он же обсервабл, не совсем понял

Comment: в компоненте `preloader$ = this.spinnerService.preloaderState$.asObservable()` -> `{{ preloader$ | async }}`